Issue installing browser with old version of flatpack
I'm using xubuntu 20.04 and i am downlaoding the broswer like chrome in flathub it always say you need later version of flatpak (1.8.2)
Help me to fix that problem

what's the output of flatpak --version

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

bro i am saying that when i am downloading flatpak apps like discord by using terminal command it always saying need later version of flatpak 1.8.2
